# Exchange 2013: content filtering bypass

Tags: exchange, spam, exchange-2013, exchange-migration, content-filter

I have just completed a migration from a single Exchange 2007 to 2xExchange 2013 servers in separate sites. Mailflow is working correctly, but the anti-spam content filtering is not working as expected.

The Exchange 2007 had GFI mail essentials running for anti-spam, for Exchange 2013, I am attempting to use the in-built anti-spam measures.

Running get-AntispamSCLHistrogram.ps1 shows around 60% of mail is bypassing the content filter, and users are complaining about the amount of spam being received. The reason being given is 'not available. content filtering was bypassed'

Content filtering is enabled.

```
[PS]>Get-ContentFilterConfig | fl *enabled*, *Bypass*, SCL*

OutlookEmailPostmarkValidationEnabled : True
SCLRejectEnabled                      : True
SCLDeleteEnabled                      : True
SCLQuarantineEnabled                  : True
Enabled                               : True
ExternalMailEnabled                   : True
InternalMailEnabled                   : True
BypassedRecipients                    : {}
BypassedSenders                       : {}
BypassedSenderDomains                 : {}
SCLRejectThreshold                    : 7
SCLRejectEnabled                      : True
SCLDeleteThreshold                    : 8
SCLDeleteEnabled                      : True
SCLQuarantineThreshold                : 6
SCLQuarantineEnabled                  : True
```

I've got the 2 Exchange servers setup in transport config.

```
[PS]>Get-TransportConfig | fl internalsmtpservers

InternalSMTPServers : {10.75.32.25, 10.75.35.25}
```

I've checked the external receive connectors only allow Anonymous users.

```
[PS]>Get-ReceiveConnector | ?{$_.Name -like "*Default Frontend*"}  | fl permissiongroups

PermissionGroups : AnonymousUsers
PermissionGroups : AnonymousUsers
```

I've got the org-wide junk scl level set.

```
[PS]>Get-OrganizationConfig | fl *scl*

SCLJunkThreshold : 5
```

What else can cause emails to bypass the content filter?

I've been pulling my hair out over this for the last few days...